# Work, Love, and Buddhism in the modern setting

Tags: modern-world, lay-buddhism, monasticism, relationship

I am curious as to what the stance of Buddhists would be towards a couple of issues.

Would it be possible to maintain a career, one that you dedicate a lot of time towards and that you actively pursue, while still devoting your life to Buddhism?

Would it be possible to maintain a physical and emotional relationship with someone?

On both of these issues I want to make a clear distinction between applying Buddhist principles towards life, and being a practicing Buddhist. I am concerned with the latter, treating the Buddhist teachings as your primary goal and giving it the utmost importance.

In essence, I am wondering if one can gain true enlightenment while remaining an active participant in the modern workspace and relationship environment, just with different principals?

As an additional tidbit, would pursuing other education or outside pleasures be possible as a monastic Buddhist?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism.SE :) I think we've had this question already in many forms... see "Related" in the sidebar.

Comment: I was worried about that, but searched and could not find much. I will keep searching though, thank you for being kind!

Comment: It's difficult to answer such broad questions... we're better equipped to deal with specific issues, like "What did the Buddha say about marriage?" etc.

Comment: Perhaps this question can reworded, along the lines of " Is enlightenment possible while staying active in the Modern Setting?" But check for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible to maintain a career, one that you dedicate a lot
>   of time towards and that you actively pursue, while still devoting
>   your life to Buddhism?

Vanijja Sutta - On Business
http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.177.than.html

Even if one is very busy with work, try to incorporate generosity, even encouraging words, an uplifting smile, live a harmless and balanced life, speak kind and truthful words, devote some time to dhamma study (say even 15 mins of reading the suttas), practice and develop even one of the four factors of mindfulness, or even one of the four right efforts, occassinally reflect on one of the three characteristics, or the dependent origination, such a person can be said to be devoted to the Dhamma.

> Would it be possible to maintain a physical and emotional relationship
>   with someone?

Suttas in relation to Nakula Matha and Nakula Pita will be helpful. They wanted to be husband and wife in the next life as well and the Buddha instructed them how to do so :)
http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/5.2-Nakula-S-a6.16-piya.pdf

Hope this helps even a little. 
May you be happy